# Redshift UNLOAD COPY Failure Data Corruption stl_load_errors MAXFILESIZE

Tags: amazon-redshift

> ## select distinct err_reason from stl_load_errors;
>
> Invalid digit, Value 'e', Pos 0, Type: Integer
>   Invalid digit, Value 'e', Pos 1, Type: Double
>   Invalid digit, Value 'b', Pos 6, Type: Integer
>   Missing data for not-null field
>   Invalid digit, Value 'N', Pos 0, Type: Long
>   Invalid digit, Value 'd', Pos 2, Type: Double
>   String length exceeds DDL length
>   Invalid digit, Value '"', Pos 6, Type: Integer
>   Invalid digit, Value 'L', Pos 0, Type: Integer
>   Delimiter not found
>   Invalid data
>   Invalid digit, Value 'D', Pos 0, Type: Integer
>   Invalid digit, Value 'c', Pos 8, Type: Integer
>   Invalid digit, Value 'f', Pos 5, Type: Integer

I was having trouble completing a data migration from one Redshift to another using the Unload and Copy functions. After a great deal of inspection it looked like there was data corruption from the UNLOAD statement, but I could not figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the UNLOAD parameter MAXFILESIZE was causing the issue. Removing it properly unloaded my data. I believe there is currently an issue with this Redshift parameter.

Comment: I was only able to recreate this error on tables > 10GB but I didn't do too much testing. I informed AWS support.